# Error! Exception of type 'ExceptionFramework.ExceptionTypes.DataAccessException

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, exception, webforms

In the asp.net application, I have got the below error. What could this possibly mean? Couldn't find an answer over the web.

> Error! Exception of type
>   'ExceptionFramework.ExceptionTypes.DataAccessException' was thrown.

Comment: An example or piece of code where the exception are being thrown could help. Are you using `Spring`?

Comment: This isn't about excpetion-handling (how to use try/catch blocks). Also  not version-specific c#4 (use c# instead). Please fix those tags when you edit your question.